# Need clarification for testing BuildConfig.DEBUG and setting build type

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

In my android application, I'm trying to run two sets of code so I can automatically change an advertising ID when I'm using Android Studio.

One for when I'm debugging in Android Studio, and one for when I build the .apk to upload to the play store.

I've been using `if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)`, but how can I be sure that that will only be true when I'm actually debugging in Android Studio, and when I build the signed .apk it will be set to false? Where should I be configuring Gradle to know what build type to use, or is this automatically done when clicking Run?

Manifest.xml

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    debug {
        applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
        debuggable true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you generate an APK, the last screen will have a dropdown that lets you choose your build type. It defaults to "Release" but you can change it to "Debug."

That's how the APK is made a debug or release APK.

Basically, if you're running the app with the play button in the top right or with Shift+F10, it'll be built as a debug APK. If you generate a signed APK, it'll be a release APK.

Comment: I see, I didn't realize it was at the last step of the process. So in any case that I click Run in Android Studio, it will run as debug, and I can choose during a signed build. Thank you for clarifying!

Answer (score 2):

You can set the variant (debug or release) that you want to build by selecting it in the `build variants` tab. Once the build is completed, you can confirm the variant by going to `app/build/generated/source/buildConfig/debug/your/package/name/BuildConfig`

Here you will see this line:

```
public static final boolean DEBUG = Boolean.parseBoolean("true");
```

When you create a release variant, you will have

```
public static final boolean DEBUG = Boolean.parseBoolean("false");
```

in `app/build/generated/source/buildConfig/release/your/package/name/BuildConfig`